# What is the difference between radd() and add( ) method of data frames in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

student = {'unit test-1':[5,6,8,3,10],'unit Test-2':[7,8,9,6,15]}
student1 = {'unit test-1':[3,3,6,6,8],'unit Test-2':[5,9,8,10,5]}
print(ds.radd(ds1))
print(ds.add(ds1))
```

When I am performing addition operation on dataframe by using `add()` and `radd()` methods then output is same of both methods.

```
unit test-1  unit Test-2
0            8           12
1            9           17
2           14           17
3            9           16
4           18           20
```

What is the difference between `add()` and `radd()`?

Comment: Check [pandas-dataframe-radd](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.radd.html#pandas-dataframe-radd)

Comment: Get Addition of dataframe and other, element-wise (binary operator add).

Equivalent to dataframe + other, but with support to substitute a fill_value for missing data in one of the inputs. With reverse version, radd.  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html

Comment: There is no difference. One performs `a+b`, the other `b+a`. Likewise `rmul` and `mul` produce the same result, but `rsub` and `sub` & `rdiv` and `div` do not.

Comment: @Gary please explain with example.i am not getting what you wants to convey.

Comment: @Nick if there is no difference then why two function with different name with same functionality? if there is little bit difference is there then plz explain with example

Comment: @manu I suspect it's probably for consistency. If you have `rsub` and `rdiv`, people might reasonably expect there to be an `rmul` and `radd`.

Comment: @Nick there is only difference between rsub and rdiv because 3-1 and 1-3 diff answer will come and 10/2 and 2/10 is answer difference. but 3*1 and 1*3 and 3+1 and 1+3 would be the same output.

Comment: @Nick am i right?

Comment: @manu that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

The result is equivalent.  You can say 'A' is added to 'B' or you can say 'B' is added to 'A'.  It's really a convenience function depending on how you visualize the element-wise addition taking place.

Links to the Panda's Documentation: [.add](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html), [.radd](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.radd.html)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i got confused with these methods too.
The real difference you'll see when performing operations like subtraction or division, since they have no commutative property.
Addition operation has a commutative property:

> a + b = b + a

while, for example, division has not:

> a / b != b / a

So:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10, 20, 2), columns=['A'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0, 10, 2), columns=['A'])
print(df1.div(df2))
print('-' * 10)
print(df1.rdiv(df2))
```

Output:

```
          A
0       inf
1  6.000000
2  3.500000
3  2.666667
4  2.250000
----------
          A
0  0.000000
1  0.166667
2  0.285714
3  0.375000
4  0.444444
```

You can think of this method like it 'reverses' operands: df2.rdiv(df1) is the same as df1.div(df2)